# VSCode / Emmet : Как при задании класса выводить атрибут class сразу после имени тега

Tags: вёрстка, visual-studio-code, emmet

В VSCode/Emmet для разворачивания аббревиатуры используется конструкция вида:

**имя_тега.имя_класса** + **Tab**

Например, `img.logo` после нажатия <kbd>Tab</kbd> преобразуется в `<img src="" alt="" class="logo">`.
Подскажите, можно ли и как изменить настройки так, чтобы при разворачивании аббревиатуры с классом, класс вставлялся сразу после имени тега? Т.е. чтобы в приведенном выше примере запись выглядела вот так:

```html
<img class="logo" src="" alt="">
```

Answer (score 2):

Для данного вопроса, необходимо добавить в файл настройки `settings.json` следующие строки

```json
"emmet.preferences": {
    "output.reverseAttributes": true
  }
```

После этого, все заработает как вы хотите

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для более тонких настроек используйте файл `snippets.json`, где можете определять более конкретное поведение. [Документация](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet#_using-custom-emmet-snippets). В этом случае не забывайте добавить путь до файла `snippets.json` через настройки либо в `settings.json`, либо через графический интерфейс пользовательских настроек.

Comment: Спасибо, вы очень помогли!

Comment: @IrinK на здоровье=)